# In a time-based association, how to obtain the effective association at any given time?

Tags: sql, time-series

Let's say I have a table of "assignments" from users to groups, where each user can be assigned to at most one group at any given time:

```sql
create table players_teams_assignments (
  user_id          integer not null,
  assignment_time  timestamp not null,
  group_id         integer,
  primary key (
    user_id, assignment_time
  )
)
```

At some arbitrary time `t`, how can I obtain all of the user IDs that are currently assigned to some arbitrary group `g`?

It is possible that there might be *zero* assigned users at time `t`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution involves constructing *intervals* of time where the assignment is active, and then filtering for intervals that cover the desired time `t`.

For example, we can do this easily using the window function `lead()`:

```sql
with assignment_intervals as (
  select
    user_id,
    assignment_time as assignment_start,
    lead(assignment_time) over (
      partition by user_id
      order by assignment_time
    ) as assignment_end,
    group_id
  from players_teams_assignments
)
select group_id
where
  assignment_start <= t and
  coalesce(assignment_end > t, true)
```

I believe `lead()` *is* part of some SQL standard (although I wouldn't know which). If your database doesn't support something like `lead()`, you will need to construct these intervals some other way.

Note the use of `coalesce` here. In Snowflake `lead()` returns `NULL` at the last row in the window. Coalescing the comparison with `true` is equivalent to treating the end of the assignment as indefinitely far in the future, representing the last-known assignment in the data.

Note also that in this case I used intervals that are closed on the left and open on the right. That is, each interval begins at the current assignment, and ends just before the next assignment. This makes sense as a default for most use cases, resulting in contiguous, disjoint interval coverage.